# Plotting 2d data in matlab with different colours according to value

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 2d array that has values -1 and 1. How do I make the imagesc(lattice) appear in 2 specific colours? Right now it shows red for -1, blue for 1, and green for 0. I want to make the places with 0 appear white.

Comment: Please provide and example of the code you have that is not working for you.

Comment: You say the array has values 1 and -1, but then you say there's also 0: ??

Comment: The array was initialised with all zeros.-/+1 were assigned afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you need to set the colormap. If you only have three values, you might set:

```
cmap = [0 0 1; 1 1 1; 1 0 0]; % sets the colors to blue, white, red\
imagesc(data); colormap(cmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [colormap](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) with those three colors:

```
cmap = [0 0 1; %// blue
        1 1 1; %// white
        1 0 0] %// red
colormap(cmap)
```